# Can an Uniswap swap return 0?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, swaps, uniswapv3

Is it possible for an Uniswap swap to return 0? Meaning, not reverting nor swapping the tokens.

Like with:

```js
function exactInputSingle(
    struct ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams params
  ) external returns (uint256 amountOut) //<---- amountOut would be 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not extremely likely, yes it is possible. Though this would take a lot more knowledge of the pools that the trading would happen on. However when you use 0 as the minimum Out, that is saying you are okay receiving 0.

On a good pool with good liquidity getting 0 is not likely but the transaction can be frontrun, and a bot can take most of the money leaving nothing but dust. But for it to truly be 0, not dust but 0, would take much more from bad liquidity to bad pool. However dust can be worth nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how it is possible. this swap() from [UniswapV2Pair.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol)

```
function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external lock {
        require(amount0Out > 0 || amount1Out > 0, 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
        (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
        require(amount0Out < _reserve0 && amount1Out < _reserve1, 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');

        uint balance0;
        uint balance1;
        { // scope for _token{0,1}, avoids stack too deep errors
        address _token0 = token0;
        address _token1 = token1;
        require(to != _token0 && to != _token1, 'UniswapV2: INVALID_TO');
        if (amount0Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
        if (amount1Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token1, to, amount1Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
        if (data.length > 0) IUniswapV2Callee(to).uniswapV2Call(msg.sender, amount0Out, amount1Out, data);
        balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
        balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
        }
        uint amount0In = balance0 > _reserve0 - amount0Out ? balance0 - (_reserve0 - amount0Out) : 0;
        uint amount1In = balance1 > _reserve1 - amount1Out ? balance1 - (_reserve1 - amount1Out) : 0;
        require(amount0In > 0 || amount1In > 0, 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
        { // scope for reserve{0,1}Adjusted, avoids stack too deep errors
        uint balance0Adjusted = balance0.mul(1000).sub(amount0In.mul(3));
        uint balance1Adjusted = balance1.mul(1000).sub(amount1In.mul(3));
        require(balance0Adjusted.mul(balance1Adjusted) >= uint(_reserve0).mul(_reserve1).mul(1000**2), 'UniswapV2: K');
        }

        _update(balance0, balance1, _reserve0, _reserve1);
        emit Swap(msg.sender, amount0In, amount1In, amount0Out, amount1Out, to);
    }
```